# How many numbers below $N$ are sieved by a certain fraction of primes?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, sieve-theory

Suppose we have an infinite sequence of primes which have an asymptotic density $1/a$ among all the primes. For convenience let  $P=\{p_a,p_{2a},...,p_{na},...\}$ be the primes we are interested in.
Can we approximate the number of natural numbers below $N$ which are divisible by at least one of the primes $\in P$ ?
It would be safe to conjecture that $N/a$ numbers are "sieved" by those primes but I am not sure if this is correct and I have not any idea how to calculate something more precise.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fraction of numbers divisible by at least one of your primes tends toward 100%. For any finite set of primes $P = \{p_a, p_{2a},\ldots,p_{ka}\}$ the fraction of numbers which are divisible by none of them is
$$
c_P = \prod_{p\in P}1 - \frac1p = \exp\sum_{p\in P}\log(1-\frac1p) \approx \exp-\sum_{p\in P}\frac1p
$$
and in particular there are $(1 - c_P)x + O(1)$ such numbers up to $x$.

But your primes are $1/a$ of primes, so the sum over all the primes in $P$ up to $x$ is asymptotically
$$
\frac{\log\log x}{e^\gamma a}(1+o(1))
$$
and since this tends to $\infty$ the constant $c_P$ is less than any positive number and hence equal to 0.

Comment: Very clever. You take a finite subset of the primes in $P$ in order to avoid the error term in the inclusion-exclusion. I think the last fraction involving Euler's constant is not relevant to the problem,but thank you for the answer anyway.+1

Comment: @KonstantinosGaitanas Right -- all that matters is that it tends to $\infty$.